# Extract part of text from file by delimiter Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, file, parsing

I have following type of text file

```
helllo
worlsadas
asdfdfsgf
eqweqqweq


asdsadsadsa
asdas
dsgfv
zczcxzfada


asdsadas
asd
safdfgdsg
asdsada

....
```

So there are two empty rows between each portion of useful text. I need to extract each portion such portion of text, for instance in array or hash(now it doesn't matter).
What is the most acceptable way to do this. I have some ideas :

1. To use regex to extract one entry `^\n\n(.*\n){1,5}\n\n`, but there
   two problems here first is that text file starts without two new
   lines, and how to get all entries in one expression or I have to
   read 8 lines and than extract code with the help of previous regex.
2. Simply read file by lines, and do some stuff each 8 line.
3. Your variant

Please suggest the right way to perform this, I am newbie, so maybe there is more convenient way to do this.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What have you got so far? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: To add to Sinan's somewhat cryptic suggestion, look at the description of `$/` (a.k.a. `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`) in [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles).  Specifying a field separator in perl will let you do it like this:

```
#!/usr/perl/bin
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    local $/ = "\n\n";
    my $count = 1;
    while (my $chunk = <DATA>) {
        print "Chunk:", $count++, "\n";
        #if you want to remove the delimiters
        $chunk =~ s/(^|\n)\n//g;
        print $chunk;
    }
}

__DATA__
helllo
worlsadas
asdfdfsgf
eqweqqweq


asdsadsadsa
asdas
dsgfv
zczcxzfada


asdsadas
asd
safdfgdsg
asdsada
```

This will print:

```
Chunk:1
helllo
worlsadas
asdfdfsgf
eqweqqweq
Chunk:2
asdsadsadsa
asdas
dsgfv
zczcxzfada
Chunk:3
asdsadas
asd
safdfgdsg
asdsada
```

Comment: Too bad there isn't a special field separator var that specifies a regex.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to extract each portion such portion of text, for instance in array or hash(now it doesn't matter).

```
((?:(?!\n\n).)+)
```

Try this.Grab the groups for `each text`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/5

Comment: Works great how can I iterate each of result I mean each portion of text (4 lines ) in perl code.

Comment: @cbyoueyq access `group 1` ,`group 2`,`and so on.

Comment: `foreach my $match ( $block_of_text =~ m/((?:(?!\n\n).)+)/igm ) { #.. }`

Answer (score 0):

Split is a good option using something like this.
Requires 2 or more pseudo *blank* lines.

`\n(?:\s*\n){2,}`

Formatted:

```
 \n (?: \s* \n ){2,}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split your text using a simple regex like this:

```
\s\s+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG2zG9/1)**

I don't know perl but for instance you can have this code in PHP:

**[Online code](http://goo.gl/NcMk6v)**

```
$input = "helllo
worlsadas
asdfdfsgf
eqweqqweq


asdsadsadsa
asdas
dsgfv
zczcxzfada


asdsadas
asd
safdfgdsg
asdsada"
print_r(preg_split('/\s\s+/', $input));
```

Output:

```
Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    [0] => helllo                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
worlsadas                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
asdfdfsgf                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
eqweqqweq                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    [1] => asdsadsadsa                                                                                                                                                                                                             
asdas                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
dsgfv                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
zczcxzfada                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    [2] => asdsadas                                                                                                                                                                                                                
asd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
safdfgdsg                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
asdsada                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
)
```

I think you can do the same in Perl with:

```
split(/\s\s+/, $input);
```

Comment: I would be quite wary of using `\s\s` - because that'll match _any_ double whitespace, which could have unintended consequences.

Comment: @Sobrique thanks for the comment I agree with you but well, I focused on the input sample OP posted